# serve existing excel files using django and pure javascript

Tags: javascript, django, excel, xlsxwriter

Im trying to serve an  existing excel file using django download it using javascript.

I tried the following code in django view:

```
Generate_Report is the io.Bytes() read from xlsxwriter.
response=HttpResponse(Generate_Report.output,content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
                        response['Content-Disposition']='attachment;filename=Report.xlsx'
                        return response
```

In html I wrote this

```
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
        {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                var downloadLink = window.document.createElement('a');
                var contentTypeHeader = xhttp.getResponseHeader("Content-Type");
                downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([xhttp.response], {type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'}));

                downloadLink.download = "Report.xlsx";
                document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
                downloadLink.click();
                document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
            }

        };
```

I want to serve an existing excel file as downloaded format.